# Building survey in React and getting errors trying to implement constraints on which questions are rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Building a survey in React and adding constraints to questions (what question is rendered next) based on previous answers, but trying to implement these constraints has left me stuck with errors.

When I run the program it is giving me an error in QuestionComponent, trying to render {question} - 'objects are not valid as a React child'

```
const questionArray = [
  {
    question: "how old are you?",
    answers: [
      "younger than 15",
      "between 15 and 20",
      "older than 20",
    ],
    questionId: 1,
  },
  {
    question: "are you a student?",
    answers: ["yes", "no"],
    questionId: 2,
    condition: ( answers ) => answers[1] !== 'Yes'
  },
  {
    question: "where do you live",
    answers: ["QLD", "NSW", "VIC", "ACT", "NT", "TAS", "WA"],
    questionId: 3,
  },
];
export default questionArray;

______________________________________________________________________________

const QuestionComponent = ({ question, answer, onSelect }) => {
  const { questions, answers } = question;
  return (
    <div>
      {question}
      {answers.map((text, index) => (
        <button
          key={index}
          onClick={() => {
            onSelect(text);
          }}
        >
          {text}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
export default QuestionComponent;

______________________________________________________________________________

import questionArray from ''
import QuestionComponent from ''

class SurveyPage extends Component {
      state = {
          answers: {}
      };

      render() { 
        const questions = questionBank.filter(q => {
            if (!q.condition) {
                return true;
            }
            return q.condition( this.state.answers );
        });   
        return (
           <div>
             {questions.map(question => (
                        <QuestionBox
                            question={question}
                            answer={this.state.answers[question.questionId]}
                            key={question.questionId}
                            onSelect={answer => {
                                const answers = {
                                    ...this.state.answers,
                                    [question.questionId]: answer,
                                };
                                this.setState({ answers });
                            }}
                        />
                    ))}
           </div>
        )
       }
}
```

Comment: "between 15 and 20" does not include 15 and 20. This may cause incorrect selections and skew your data. I suppose you meant to say "inclusive".

Comment: const { questions, answers } = question; this is an object.
you are passing question object inside <div> directly.

Comment: So made it past that initial problem of rendering an object, now I think the last issue is in the question array. I've got a condition inside one of the questions but its giving me the error '(destructured parameter) is undefined' where it says condition: ({answers}) => answers[1] === 'Yes'. My answers are being stored in state on 'SurveyPage', so is having the condition inside the question objects possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should pass the `QuestionArr` to your survey component and in turn loop through the QuestionArr in your survey component and then pass the current question to your Question Component.